# How to use .htaccess to redirect a string?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to set up a redirect for several thousand always changing URLS.

FROM THIS - `example.com/product?product_id=blue_alwayschanging`

TO THIS - `example.com/widget?product_id=blue_alwayschanging`

With my limited knowledge, I'm thinking something like the below is a step in the right direction. What am I missing? It's not working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^/product?product_id=blue_.* /widget?product_id=.*
```

Comment: Justy to clarify, your example copies the query string unchanged from the source to the target. However, your "non working" code appears to suggest that you want to remove the string "blue_" from the parameter value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteEngine` activates mod_rewrite. Whereas `RedirectMatch` is a mod_alias directive. `RedirectMatch` also does not match against the query string, but then you don't need to, since the query string simply needs to be passed onto the target unchanged.

Try replacing your current code with the following one-liner:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/product /widget
```